# How to correct "invalid outside procedure" error?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have been coding in VB for a student management system and once I try to I get an error "invalide outside procedure".

Here is the code:

Form Login

```
Option Explicit
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim constr As String

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
 'set the global var to false '
    'to denote a failed login '

    LoginSucceeded = False
    Me.Hide

End Sub
```

Comment: VB.NET and VB6 are different languages. Which one do you mean?

Comment: Maybe you could specify what line the error refers to.

Comment: Looks like VB6.  Change `Dim` to `Private` and see if that works for you.

Comment: This code works for me.  Your error must be someplace else.

Comment: What Brian said: the code works fine, so the error must occur with the code that follows up.

Comment: I don't think we are getting the full code. Where is `LoginSucceeded` declared?